# Postgresql with Play (Scala) unresolved dependency

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework-2.0

When I try to run my server, I get this Error:

> sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency:
>   postgresql#postgresql;42.1.0: not found

This happens with every version of postgresql I've yet tried, so I really don't see why. I've added the dependency in my build.sbt file like so:

```
libraryDependencies += "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.1.0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this: `libraryDependencies += "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.1.0"` into build.sbt file

Comment: UPDATE: the "org.postgresql" actually was the mistake, I only put "postgresql". Thank you so much!